# Why MediaFoundation InitializeSinkWriter (SetInputMediaType) only accepts WMV3 format?

Tags: c++, winapi, video, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

Taken from the MSDN help pages, InitializeSinkWriter works fine so long as the video encoding and video input format is WMV3/RGB32, however if I change it to WMV1, MPEG2, etc. then SetInputMediaType fails.

AFAIK I have WMV1 installed as a codec according to Sherlock the Codec Detective program.

Here is the code that causes the issue:
(to find the problem code, search for "problem" in source comments, there is a lot of boiler plate code that is irrelevant)

```
// Format constants
const UINT32 VIDEO_WIDTH = 640;
const UINT32 VIDEO_HEIGHT = 480;
const UINT32 VIDEO_FPS = 30;
const UINT64 VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION = 10 * 1000 * 1000 / VIDEO_FPS;
const UINT32 VIDEO_BIT_RATE = 800000;
const GUID   VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_WMV1 ; // problem here, must be WMV3
const GUID   VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_WMV3 ;    // problem here if not wmv3 too
const UINT32 VIDEO_PELS = VIDEO_WIDTH * VIDEO_HEIGHT;
const UINT32 VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT = 20 * VIDEO_FPS;

HRESULT InitializeSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex)
{
    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter   *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    DWORD           streamIndex;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"output.wmv", NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

    // Set the output media type.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);
    }

    // Set the input media type.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Problem here! Codec issue with wmv1, mpeg, etc.
        hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);  
    }
    else {
        puts("setattributeratio failed");
    }

    // Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
    } 
    else {
        puts("setinputmediatype failed");  // <-- HR result problem here
    }
    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
        (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
        *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;
    }
    else {
        puts("beginwriting failed");
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);
    return hr;
}
```

Initialize sink writer is called with this code:

```
void main()
{
    DWORD streamidx = 0;
    const WCHAR *SAMPLE_FILE = L"sample.wmv";
    IMFSourceReader *pReader = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter *pWriter = NULL;
    puts("Initializing...");

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // problem here !
            hr = InitializeSinkWriter(&pWriter, &streamidx);  
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // more code would go here...

            }
            else {
                puts("InitializeSinkWriter failed"); // this is called
            }

            SafeRelease(&pWriter);
            MFShutdown();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
    puts("Finished...");
}
```

This is a standard Windows 7 computer I am using, so, if it only accepts WMV3 as the encoder or input type, does it mean I have to install codecs? This seems absurd since popular formats like WMV1 and MPEG should already be installed, and Sherlock codec detective says they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for codecs you are trying in Windows Media Foundation (even though some third party software could report availability of other codecs for other APIs).

See:

- [Supported Media Formats in Media Foundation - Video Codecs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927#Video_Codecs) - Encoder column in the table under Video Codecs
- [Windows Media Video 9 Encoder - Output Fomats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819505#Output_Formats) - there is no WMV1 there

Comment: interesting, so technically the old Video for Windows (VFW) although obsolete, is technically superior since virtually any codec can be used to compress a video with VFW, by selecting a compresor of your desire?
Is the alternative to VFW, since it's old, possibly another tool? DirectShow possibly

Comment: also, why does the API have these constants for WMV1 if they are not  usable? i.e. MFVideoFormat_WMV1 is an orphan constant that is available, but not acceptable? How come? Obsoleted? Used to be used back in the Vista days? Or they put these constants here for future use? There are tons of constants prefixed with MFVideoFormat_ in the API and only a few are really usable?

Comment: Well yes, it is one of the downsides of Media Foundation. it is generally assumed/expected that new API has a recipe for every older use case and there is a way to migrate. The reality is that in Media Foundation Microsoft took much of flexibility back, compared to DirectShow, and did not provide sufficient tooling to migrate. DirectShow remains the most flexible and developer friendly.

Comment: My guess is that Media Foundation decoder can still play WMV1 content even though it's not in the documentation. The encoder part however won't produce new WMV1 content. Presumably, Microsoft expects those to need richer WMV1 support to create their own MFTs to support this format (such as by, for example, wrapping Windows Media Format SDK) and extend Media Foundation that way. This is why they defined the identifier - should you need one for your own MF primitive, you already have it defined by the SDK.

Comment: Does directshow offer the flexibility of VFW, to choose a compressor of your choice? (there are also patent/royalty issues in these cases too, but I don't care about that at the moment ;-))

Comment: DirectShow [does offer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374572) flexibility of using an encoder of choice, even though I see the same codec set in standard DMO there: WMV3, WVC1, WMVP, WVP2.

Comment: Okay, regarding directshow, I have asked a question instead of filling the comment section here with too much discussion. I am wondering about Decoding in directshow whether you can choose a decoder, like vfw (not just encoder).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854895/does-directshow-allow-one-to-decode-virtually-any-video-based-on-installed-codec