# Does DirectShow allow one to decode virtually any video based on installed codecs?

Tags: visual-studio, directshow, video-processing, ms-media-foundation, vfw

I am comparing VFW, MediaFoundation, and DirectShow.. Although VFW is very old and dated, it at least allows a lot of flexibility in encoding and decoding videos because you can choose virtually any encoder/decoder, AFAIK, and you are not limited to a subset of decoders/encoders that only microsoft has chosen.

Does DirectShow offer the ability to decode (decompress) multiple video kinds (like vfw) using any chosen codec, or must you only use a subset that microsoft has chosen?

Indeed some api's require writing your own custom system to decode, but I am wondering about "out of the box" functionality (ready to use) without as much custom code required. VFW (video for windows) seems to offer this, by using pre-ready decoders/encoders with no work required by you, but VFW is dated and might be obsolete at some point - but seems to require the least coding effort.

Answer (score 2):

DirectShow is flexible and is open to developer. Such openness is from time to time abused and is a point of criticism:

> [Codec hell (a term derived from DLL hell) is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow#Codec_hell) when multiple DirectShow filters conflict for performing the same task. A large number of companies now develop codecs in the form of DirectShow filters, resulting in the presence of several filters that can decode the same media type

Also, DirectShow did not receive any significant development for many years and for this reasons is sometimes thought of as deprecated, which is not quite true, and a great deal of software out there including Microsoft's own are still heavily dependent on DirectShow. [“… you will never get the same high quality video experience that you find with DirectShow”](http://alax.info/blog/1632) - I have a few quotes collected here and they are in good standing.

Yes you can build pipelines flexibly and use decoders/encoders (as well as other parts of pipeline collectively referred to as "filters") of your choice.

DirectShow API offers the widest choice of third party components, is covered by a multitude of samples on Internet, is way more powerful than VFW and not as restrictive and scarce as Media Foundation. Yet it's somewhat outdated, dependent on pretty old BaseClasses code base in customized development and is generally known to have a steep learning curve.

To get a quick idea about DirectShow you can download the best interactive tool for DirectShow development [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) and use menu File, Render Media File to build a playback pipeline for standard media files like .MP4s. You will be able to change the pipeline interactively and this is presenting what you are supposed to do programmatically as well.

Comment: does VFW suffer from any codec hell, of multiple VFW codecs conflicting with each other?

Thanks for the knowledgeable answers on all my video/media posts!

Comment: VFW API is alot simpler and you rarely have a lot of third party components so that they compete one with another, then there is no such level of sophistication of the API itself that it picks not the component you expected, so you don't face codec hell there.

Comment: only issue with VFW I can see in that regard is that there may be a missing codec that is not vfw compatible, as, for example people have complained about VirtualDub only being a vfw system that doesn't have non vfw codecs. This is something I will have to look into, if separate codecs are needed just for VFW, then maybe there are some missing codecs if people decided not to make a codec to target vfw. I don't know if there are multi codecs that work with vfw and others all in one. I am a newbie in this area of programming so trying to sort it out before making the wrong decision early in dev.

Comment: There are no all-in-one codecs. VFW codecs are very rare and VFW development in many cases does not make sense. DirectShow "sees" VFW codecs though and make them available by providing a wrapper. It does not work the other way though. Still, there is x264vfw and consumption of a VFW codec standalone is way easier compared to DirectShow (if you need just the narrow encoding part and nothing else).